# XML Schema Error location - How I can find location of 'position' and 'line'?

Tags: xml, notepad++, schema

When I do Schema validation test, below message is appeared.

**XML didn't pass validation with the schema (DTD) and attribute files(10)**

Validation error in **line 1 at position 3717** : The 'm3-2-s-mpt0b640' element is not declared.
Validation error in **line 1 at position 5032** : The 'ID' attribute has an invalid value according to its data type.

Please let me know how to find the location of Line 1 at position 5032?? 
I use NOTEPAD++ for editing XML files.

Comment: The status line at the bottom of the window shows the line and column numbers of the cursor. On an empty file it shows"Ln: 1  Col: 1".

Answer (score 0):

You need to indent your XML file via **Pretty print (XML only)** option in the XML Tools plugin, and re-run the validation. After that line and position values will be much more meaningful.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however I cannot still find the position.. please kindly let me know how to find the location of the position..

Comment: Please update your original post, and share a sample of your XML

Answer (score 0):

The status line at the bottom of the window shows the line and column numbers of the cursor. On an empty file it shows"Ln: 1 Col: 1". Try moving the cursor through the file until "Ln" and "Col" show the wanted numbers.